# Script in /etc/cron.hourly/ never running

Tags: centos, cron

I have a script in /etc/cron.hourly :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 85 Dec  6 19:05 /etc/cron.hourly/nvidia_to_exclusive
```

containing (with an empty line at the end):

```
#!/bin/bash 

/usr/bin/nvidia-smi -c 1 > /home/user/nvidia-smi_set_exclusive.log
```

The script isn't executed by cron at all, even if using **`run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` successfully** execute it.

**What could be missing ?**

Comment: Does anything show in `/var/log/cron`?  eg mine says  `Dec 11 16:01:01 mercury7 CROND[30644]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 11 16:01:01 mercury7 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30644]: starting 0anacron
Dec 11 16:01:01 mercury7 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[30667]: finished 0anacron`.   Errors may show, here.

Comment: No, except when I manually call `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly`, then it say that it started/fnished Anacron0, then the same for my script.  
It's seems that `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` isn't called.

Comment: Is it set executable? :)

Comment: What be the contents of `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: @tink yes, I don't think run-parts would works without that (and confirmed by ls anyway) :).

Comment: @RudiC nothing except the initialization of variables (SHELL, PATH and MAILTO) and comments, but as I understood, there is no need to put a line in crontab when using /etc/cron.hourly directory, does it ?

Comment: @RudiC `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` contains `01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` and should be the one that execute the hourly cron job if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure `cron` runs every hour...

Comment: Oh... Thanks @RudiC, I've verified if cron was running using `service crond status` and it's inactive... I'll restart it and keep you informed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that the cron service was inactive.

While I'm here, I'll summarize all the steps I've found to make a script in `/etc/cron.hourly/` work :

- Check that the name of your script is only using valid characters for `run-parts`, i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_-].
  So **don't** use extension like `.sh`.
- Check that your script is executable.
  If not : `chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/yourScript`
- Check that your script contains the shebang at the top (`#!/bin/bash` for example).
- Check that your script runs with `run-parts` :
  `run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly` → your script should be printed.
  `run-parts /etc/cron.hourly`→ your script should be executed.
  You can check at the end of `/var/log/cron` if your script successfully finished.
- Check that cron is running with `service crond status`.
  If not : `service crond stop`  then `service crond start`
- Check if your `/var/log/cron` contains the error `BAD FILE MODE (/etc/cron.d/0hourly)`.
  If it's the case, you probably need to execute `chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/0hourly` (cron does not like this file to be executable).
- Check - at least by default on CentOS 7 - that `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` exists and contains the line
  `01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly`

Comment: Excellent self-answer, glad you got it working. You should accept your answer as well, just to close the cycle

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Helped a lot!

Comment: Oh boy, thank you! We had the `.sh` extension in one of our scripts and nobody noticed for TWO YEARS that this script did actually never run...